# How to count occurrences of each distinct value for every column in a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

`edf.select("x").distinct.show()` shows the distinct values that are present in `x` column of `edf` DataFrame.

Is there an efficient method to also show the number of times these distinct values occur in the data frame? (count for each distinct value)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`countDistinct` is probably the first choice:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct

df.agg(countDistinct("some_column"))
```

If speed is more important than the accuracy you may consider `approx_count_distinct` (`approxCountDistinct` in Spark 1.x):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct

df.agg(approx_count_distinct("some_column"))
```

To get values and counts:

```
df.groupBy("some_column").count()
```

In SQL (`spark-sql`):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT some_column) FROM df
```

and

```sql
SELECT approx_count_distinct(some_column) FROM df
```

Answer (score 16):

### Roughly speaking, how it works:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Another option without resorting to sql functions

```
df.groupBy('your_column_name').count().show()
```

*show* will print the different values and their occurrences. The result without show will be a dataframe.

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct

df.groupBy("a").agg(countDistinct("s")).collect()
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer further on how it works?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java, then `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct;`  will give an error :
`The import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct cannot be resolved`

To use the `countDistinct` in java, use the below format:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;

df.agg(functions.countDistinct("some_column"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.select("some_column").distinct.count
```

Comment: Does this tell you how count of each distinct values? I think this would tell you that you have X values, not that Val1 has A, Val2 has B,.. ValX has C?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: This is too slow to compute, the best bet is using `countDistinct`